# Is it possible to point multiple domains to multiple static IP's on a single system?

Tags: ubuntu, static-ip, ip-forwarding

I'm currently running the latest version of Ubuntu Server. I currently am pointing my subdomain to my static IP address. I have 5 static IP's and I'm wondering how I could use all static IP's at once so I can give each domain its own IP. If not, is there a better way too go about this?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, just setup DNS A records.

Comment: But how would I connect my computer to multiple static IP's?

Comment: @AnonymousUser You assign the IPs to the computer's interface[s].

Comment: So for five IP's I need five interfaces or in my case five ethernet slots?

Comment: @AnonymousUser No, you may use a single NIC.

Comment: So, I can do this all with 'sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces'

Comment: Refer to your OS documentation. You can have multiple IPs on one interfaces, usually it's called IP alias.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100715/how-to-set-up-multiple-ip-addresses

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, indeed it's the easiest way to configure multiple SSL hostnames.

As to how you achieve that....it depends. If you're doing NAT on your router, just map the static addresses to the address of the host. If your router just does routing then add the IP addresses on the NIC connected to the router.